# Python acting strange when trying to call wget with encoding for Japanese

Tags: python, bash, encoding, wget, cjk

I'm creating a python script that uses bash to do a wget on a list of Japanese words contained in a file. I would just use curl but this had encoding problems. With wget it does download the html, but it dumps it in the current directory with poetic titles such as:

```
   試%E8%A1%8C%E9%8C%AF誤
```

I want it to put the html into pretty-sounding places like "output/混合.txt". It does create these pretty-sounding files, but with nothing in them.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os

with open("words") as f:
    for line in f:
        text = unicode(line, "utf-8")
        os.system("wget \'https://kotobank.jp/word/" + line.strip() + "'> output/" + line.strip() + ".txt")
        #print("wget \'https://kotobank.jp/word/" + line.strip() + "'>> output/out.txt")
```

And the file "words" is as follows:

```
追究
花器
陶磁器
枯渇
風合い
繊維
混合
アボード
受け継い
試行錯誤
硬質
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-O file` option instead of redirecting the output:

```
os.system("wget \'https://kotobank.jp/word/" + line.strip() + "' -O " + line.strip() + ".txt"
```

See `wget` [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Download-Options) for more information.